# A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, spread-syntax

I am new to TypeScript and I am going to change my project to TypeScript.
But I got some error.
I have searched about the spread arguments but I can't figure it out correctly.

This is I tried so far.

```
export const fetcher = async (...args) => {
    return fetch(...args).then(async (res) => {
        let payload;
        try {
            if (res.status === 204) return null; // 204 does not have body
            payload = await res.json();
        } catch (e) {
            /* noop */
        }
        if (res.ok) {
            return payload;
        } else {
            return Promise.reject(payload.error || new Error('Something went wrong'));
        }
    });
};
```

But it throws an error like this line:

```
return fetch(...args).then(async (res) => {
```

> A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter

Comment: Why do you have a `}` after `...args` in line 2?

Comment: you must give `...args` a type -> `async (...args: Parameters<typeof fetch>) => ...`

Comment: Thanks Tobias S. It works. But I still can't know why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not give `args` a type. Because it is a *spread argument*, TypeScript automatically types it as `any[]`.

In JavaScript, you can spread an array into the arguments of a function call. This is called a *spread argument*. To make this type-safe, the type of the array you are spreading must be a *tuple type*. `any` is normally seen as an escape hatch which disables type checking. But spread arguments are an exception where even `any` is not allowed.

The signature of `fetch` looks like this:

```
function fetch(input: RequestInfo | URL, init?: RequestInit | undefined)
```

If you want to pass an array (in this case `args`) via *spread argument*, the tuple type of `args` must then look like this:

```
args: [input: RequestInfo | URL, init?: RequestInit | undefined]
```

Because we are lazy and don't want to type this out by hand, we can use the [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) utility type. We can pass `typeof fetch` to `Parameters` and it will return the tuple type of the parameters of `fetch` for us.

```
export const fetcher = async (...args: Parameters<typeof fetch>) =>
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgMZQHYGdEDMRyQCxBgQF4EBDdAT1SQQAoA6Z8mAc3QC4EAFV8gLa4i6ADxwqEEFCwIcefAD4AlKUUIA3sAQ6EMXAFcYqObgJMW7dMsZxCqepRp16+62s3bd3gDa4EEORUPlDkACYA3F7eOnAwVJ4xSQgAlrKuIOiMmORwBuikJGQATAAMACyq+nnGCKgGPj4RCAD0LQhl5QhhUJl1UIj45ABuIAgARlBhVNHJOoHBoWGkFADu5CmIbowAVuho9MpRcwC+yLkEDCCqWnPeLQBU-VAQCA8ts94nn7ppDNtQADWNx+SWqRhMCxC4WOyTOIB86DGtzuOnBtR4MCgAhSSMY+h2ICQcHoUKWjCIWOIAB9qXUQKsEABRGBU+gAcgAytjcPgUqg2AhViBUIhVliBezlEdQQhvl8ZScIkA)